# Change position of text inside AnchorPane?

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I have got the following code where I am adding a circle inside my anchorpane, and onto the circle I am adding a text.

Circle is an Circle, ArrayList, with multiple circles.

```
    pane.getChildren().addAll(circle);


        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle.stream().map(circ -> {
            Label text = new Label(circ.getId());
            text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(text, circ.getCenterX());
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(text, circ.getCenterY());
            return text;
        }).toArray(Label[]::new));
}
```

I can change the position from my circle with circle.get(i).setCenterY();

But how can I change the position of the text I added onto the circle?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can change with the same code you used to set it initially: `AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(text, newXValue)`. You might need to be more specific about the actual problem.

Comment: What does that "map..." do ? When I want to access "text" from outside, I can't I want to make text change the same position when circle is changing it's position

Comment: What do you mean by "What does that map do?". You wrote that code.

Comment: My question is, how can I change the position of the text (label)? I can access the circle with "circle.get(i).setCenterY();" but how can I access my text label?

Comment: OK, but that's not actually the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

To access the labels, you need to keep a reference to them, e.g.

```
pane.getChildren().addAll(circle);

List<Label> labels = circle.stream().map(circ -> {
    Label text = new Label(circ.getId());
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(text, circ.getCenterX());
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(text, circ.getCenterY());
    return text;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());


pane.getChildren().addAll(labels);
```

And now of course you can just do

```
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(labels.get(i), newXValue);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(labels.get(i), newYValue);
```